# On the impossibility of stable equilibrium of a charge in an electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law, stability

I had read from my textbook that a positive charge cannot be in stable equilibrium as if we take a gaussian surface surrounding the charge then assuming that the charge is in equilibrium then using Gauss's law we find that as the external electric field lines produce a negative flux on the surface hence the LHS of the equation is negative and the RHS is positive which is not possible so this setup is not possible.

Here I cannot understand why the flux of the electric field lines due to the positive charge is not taken. If we consider that then the equation might be valid and the LHS might become positive if the magnitude of the flux due to the positive charge's electric field is more the
the magnitude of the flux due to the external electric field.

EDIT: Isn't flux due to an external electric field zero as the number of electric field line entering and leaving the closed gaussian surface is equal so why is it saying that the flux is negative shouldn't it be always positive as the net flux is now only due to the positive charge itself.

The text says:

> Impossibility of stable equilibrium of a charge
> in an electric field. Suppose that we have in vacuum a system of fixed
> point charges in equilibrium. Let us consider one of these charges,
> e.g. a charge q. Can its equilibrium be stable?
> In order to answer this question, let us envelop the charge q by a
> small closed surface S (Fig. 1.6). For the sake of definiteness, we assume
> that q > 0. For the equilibrium of this charge to be stable, it is
> necessary that the field E created by all the remaining charges of the
> system at all the points of the surface S be directed towards the charge
> q. Only in this case any small displacement of the charge q from the
> equilibrium position will give rise to a restoring force, and the equilibrium
> state will actually be stable. But such a configuration of the
> field E around the charge q is in contradiction to the Gauss theorem:
> the flux of E through the surface S is negative, while in accordance
> with the Gauss theorem it must be equal to zero since it is created by
> charges lying outside the surface S. On the other hand, the fact that
> E is equal to zero indicates that at some points of the surface S vector
> E is directed inside it and at some other points it is directed outside.
> Hence it follows that in any electrostatic field a charge cannot be in
> stable equilibrium

Comment: It may help you to look up the [Earnshow's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem), which is the formal name for the lack of stable equilibrium for a system of charges.

Comment: I feel my current knowledge is insufficient to understand such complex affairs could you please explain where i am going wrong ?

Comment: It is not clear from your question what your equation is - I think you need to add more details, so that one can understand what exactly is your problem/misunderstanding, and how it is resolved.

Comment: The flux of the charge's field should not be taken into account since the charge cannot exert electric force on itself

Comment: Please show the source and actual text. Your description is confusing.

Comment: @Roger Vadim total flux via the gaussian surface=(Qenclosed/e0)